# Convergence of $s/σ$ in probability

Tags: probability, statistics, convergence-divergence, parameter-estimation, estimation

I have been asked to prove that $s/\sigma$ converges to 1 in probability, where $s$ and $\sigma$ are from a Normal distribution, $s$ representing the sample standard deviation and $\sigma$ is just our standard deviation.

I know from a previous example that I have solved that $s_n^2$ is a consistent estimator of $\sigma^2$. But now I don't know how to move ahead or what I could do from here.

Really hoping for some help on this .

Comment: Hint: $\lvert s_n - \sigma \rvert < \epsilon$ is the same as $-\epsilon < s_n-\sigma<\epsilon$. Relate this to the ration $s_n/\sigma$.

Comment: It follows immediately from  the continuous mapping theorem, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem

Comment: @BotnakovN. to be sure, for continuous mapping theorem we prove that a function is continuous over a domain and use that to prove convergence in probability for a given random variable?

Comment: @AndrewZhang I get it now, thanks a lot

Comment: @randomvlad To use continuous mapping theorem, if $X_n \overset{p}{\to}X$, then to conclude $g(X_n)\overset{p}{\to}g(X)$, you need that $g$ is continuous almost surely with respect to the law of $X$.

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense, thanks a lot @AndrewZhang

Answer (score 1):

Consider function $f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sigma}$ which is continious on $[0, \infty)$.
We know that $s_n^2 \overset{P}{\to}\sigma^2$ hence $f(s_n^2) \overset{P}{\to} f(\sigma^2)$ so $\frac{s_n}{\sigma} \overset{P}{\to} 1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Botnakov, really sorry that I'm thanking you late but I had something come up. But this is really helpful, appreciate the help!

Comment: @randomvlad You are welcome!